# Python More efficient permutation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, permutation, combinatorics

I have a string that consists of x amount of the letter 'r' and y amount of 'u'. And my goal is two print all possible combinations of that same amount of x,y with different orders. This my example of a working code.

```
import itertools
RIGHT = 'r'
UP = 'u'
def up_and_right(n, k, lst):
    case = RIGHT*n + UP*k
    return [''.join(p) for p in set(itertools.permutations(case))]
```

Example input and output:

```
input:
lst1 = []
up_and_right(2,2,lst1)
lst1 => output:['ruru', 'urur', 'rruu', 'uurr', 'urru', 'ruur']
```

My problem is when the input is an integer more than 10 the code takes a minute to compute. How can I improve the compute time?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since `lst_case` already contains the desired combinations, you could simply use `return lst_case` instead of looping through the list once again.

Comment: You are right made the correction but I was talking more about improving on the permutations initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `itertools.combinations`:

```py
import itertools

RIGHT = "r"
UP = "u"


def up_and_right(n, k):
    out = []
    for right_idxs in itertools.combinations(range(n + k), r=n):
        s = ""
        for idx in range(n + k):
            if idx in right_idxs:
                s += RIGHT
            else:
                s += UP
        out.append(s)
    return out


print(up_and_right(2, 2))
```

Prints:

```py
['rruu', 'ruru', 'ruur', 'urru', 'urur', 'uurr']
```

---

With one-liner:

```py
def up_and_right(n, k):
    return [
        "".join(RIGHT if idx in right_idxs else UP for idx in range(n + k))
        for right_idxs in itertools.combinations(range(n + k), r=n)
    ]
```

Comment: Why Did you use range inside the combination method?

Comment: @Dan7nm I use `itertools.combinations(range(n + k), r=n)` to get all indices where the RIGHT symbol should go in final string.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is about finding [permutations of multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets). `sympy` has a utility method that deals with it.

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations
def up_and_right2(n,k):
    case = RIGHT*n + UP*k
    return list(map(''.join, multiset_permutations(case)))
```

Test:

```
y = up_and_right(n,k)
x = up_and_right2(n,k)
assert len(x) == len(y) and set(y) == set(x)
```

Timings:

```
n = 5
k = 6
%timeit up_and_right(n,k)
3.57 s ± 52.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit up_and_right2(n,k)
4.17 ms ± 159 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```